# Resolver problema Min Window Substring en C#

Tags: c#

> **Min Window Substring**
>
> Have the function `MinWindowSubstring(strArr)` take the array of strings stored in `strArr`, which will contain only two strings, the first parameter being the string `N` and the second parameter being a string `K` of some characters, and your goal is to determine the smallest substring of `N` that contains all the characters in `K`.
>
> For example: if `strArr` is `["aaabaaddae", "aed"]` then the smallest substring of `N` that contains the characters `a`, `e`, and `d` is "dae" located at the end of the string. So for this example your program should return the string `dae`.
>
> Another example: if `strArr` is `["aabdccdbcacd", "aad"]` then the smallest substring of `N` that contains all of the characters in `K` is "aabd" which is located at the beginning of the string. Both parameters will be strings ranging in length from 1 to 50 characters and all of `K`'s characters will exist somewhere in the string `N`. Both strings will only contains lowercase alphabetic characters.
>
> ```
> Examples
> Input: new string[] {"ahffaksfajeeubsne", "jefaa"}
> Output: aksfaje
> Input: new string[] {"aaffhkksemckelloe", "fhea"}
> Output: affhkkse
> ```

En verdad les quedaría enormemente agradecido.

No sé cómo empezar. Lo siento soy principiante.

```
using System;

class MainClass {

  public static string MinWindowSubstring(string[] strArr) {

    
    return strArr[0];

  }

  static void Main() {  



    // keep this function call here
    Console.WriteLine(MinWindowSubstring(Console.ReadLine()));
  } 

}
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Por otro lado, veo que no has hecho ni intentado nada. ¿Has probado a hacer un curso de programación? Suele ser muy útil para aprender a programar algoritmos como éste. Por cierto, ¿podrías al menos traducir los requerimientos?

Comment: Pasadas más de tres horas sin respuesta del OP, voto el cierre de la pregunta por no estar en castellano, idioma oficial de este sitio web, o incluso que no puede reproducirse el error.